# Allowing elements to float off the screen horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm in a bit of a pickle here, i have 6 `<li>` element sets in the same `<ul>`. [Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/ixibed/1/edit). My goal is to allow the elements to overflow off the right of the page and I will cycle through them later with javascript. For some reason no matter what I try it just pushes the other elements down. i have tried:

```
float:left;

display:inline-block;
```

every flavor of display actually, also tried `clear:both;` I have also tried setting the list in a div and setting the width to a ridiculous pixel width and hoping that would push it off the edge properly but it did nothing.

Any ideas?

I want to try to avoid javascript solutions, but everything is welcome.

note:
eventually these will be more that 20% width, each `<li>` will span the screen width and move in when jquery says so

Comment: Have you tried the CSS "left/top" properties?  Setting left:9999px; should push that element way off of the screen.

Comment: @MikeMarks i would like them to sit next to each other, sure i could margin everything over and up (same with positioning) but thats a really sucky way to do stuff. there has to be another solution.

Comment: Change you min-height to 100 in the demo, it's hard to tell what's going on when you have it set at 800px

Comment: Understood.  I know a lot of JavaScript navigation menus use that type of method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your li width a fixed width instead of 20%, if you have it as a percentage then it doesn't matter how big your container is, the li will always be 20% of that width.

Also make sure the li container has a big enough width to contain your li's

Something like this

http://jsbin.com/eyemaf/1/edit  Hope this link works I don't usually use jsbin

```
.bodynavs{
    width:200px;
    min-height:100px;
    border:1px solid green;
}

#slideimages{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 2000%;
}
```

Comment: This makes complete sense, i cant believe i didnt think about the percentage consistency. Probably about time to call it a day. Thanks.

Comment: the only thing i really dont care too much for about this solution is that i would like each li to take up the whole page and if i set that with pixels there is no surefire way of that hapening like there is with percentages. Any chance you have an idea for that?

Comment: you can try the nowrap thing, specifying li being inline-block (no float) and put nowrap on your ul. It just seem a bit hacky. If you go the nowrap way, make sure you declare white-space: normal for your li

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to try changing the `white-space` CSS property:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

This will cause your list elements to be all on one line, going off-screen as intended, to be scrolled in as necessary.

Comment: that's not the same code the OP provided, he has the width as a percentage instead of a fixed width

Comment: How's it a hack? It's a built in CSS declaration.

Comment: because it forces you to declare extra css for the li to not have nowrap

Comment: Be that as it may, *personally*, I find that having to declare a ridiculously large width to be even more of a hack. To each their own I suppose.